# How to get title, name and description for an image that I upload in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I wrote this Query:

```
$album_id = get_the_id();
$photos = $wpdb->get_results(
    "select * from wp_postmeta where post_id = '"
    . $album_id
    . "' AND meta_key = 'gallery_ph' order by meta_id desc"
);
```

Now, I want to get all thumbnails with title, name and description for this images.

I found in the DB:

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key   | meta_value
577     | 346     | gallery_ph | http://url to the image
```

and the thumbnail

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key                 | meta_value
569     | 348     | _wp_attachment_image_alt | Jury Datiop
```

How are this two datas connected? I know that Jury Datiop has the url `http://xxx` because I can check in wp-admin. But how to write the select query? How to connect image and get title, name, description?

Comment: Where are you using the data? In a theme template or plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to query the database directly.

WordPress has a whole lot of custom functions for you to retrieve the data that you need.

Check the:

### [WordPress Codex : Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/)

#### Specially:

- [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts)
- [`get_children`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children)
- [`wp_get_attachment_metadata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata)

---

### Translation of your database query to a WordPress function:

<sup>***code not tested, use the Debug to inspect the results of each operation***</sup>

```
$album_id = get_the_id();

$photos = get_children( array(
    'post_parent'    => $album_id, 
    'post_type'      => 'attachment', 
    'meta_key'       => 'gallery_ph', 
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
    'order'          => 'DESC', 
    'orderby'        => 'meta_id') 
);

// DEBUG
// echo '<pre>' . print_r( $meta, true ) . '</pre>';

if( $photos )
{
    foreach( $photos as $img )
    {
        // DEBUG
        // echo '<pre>' . print_r( $img, true ) . '</pre>';

        $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $img->ID );
        
        // DEBUG
        // echo '<pre>' . print_r( $meta, true ) . '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but wp_get_attachment_metadata($pot_id) not working in template. I get no output. I am using it in portfolio. Can you give me an example?

Comment: **`$pot_id`**?? Make sure you are using the correct variable names. Also `wp_get_attachmente_metadata` needs the *Attachment ID*, not the post's. :::: Please, add details to the Question, i.e.: *the context where you are implementing this code*.

Comment: Take a look at the sample code, that would be enough to get you started. ***Consult the Codex to understand how each function works.*** As you are not showing your whole code, I assume you are doing this inside the Loop, and recommend converting the example into a function inside your `functions.php`. Then, from inside the loop call it like: `print_my_thumbnails( $album_id );`.